# Interaction between Activity and Sticky Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

i have an **Activity** and a **Sticky Service**. The Activity needs to show some values in it´s UserInterface depending on the values of the Sticky Service. So **whenever** the Service changes his data, the Activity needs to update it´s UserInterface. 
But how should the **Service notify the Activity** to change it´s values??

Please remind that the Activity sometimes isn´t alive, only the Service is Sticky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LocalBroadcasts

in your service class:

```
public class LocalMessage extends IntentService{
    private Intent broadcast;
    public static final String BROADCAST = "LocalMessage.BROADCAST";
    public LocalMessage(String name) {
        super(name);
        broadcast = new Intent(name);
    }

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (broadcast != null) LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

and here is method inside service to broadcast

```
private void sendLocalMessage(){
    (new LocalMessage(LocalMessage.BROADCAST)).onHandleIntent(null);
}
```

In your activity:

```
    private void registerBroadcastReciever() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YourService.LocalMessage.BROADCAST);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    } 
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//doSmth
                }
            };
```

in your activity onDestroy() method unregister receiver;

Comment: Which context do you use in onHandleIntent()? If I use getApplicationContext i get a NullPointer:                        11-02 19:45:57.922: E/AndroidRuntime(21590): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 19:45:57.922: E/AndroidRuntime(21590):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)

Comment: context defined in @Override
    public void onCreate() {
  context = getApplicationContext(); ...} method of service