# Calling Activity Method In Fragment Causing Application To Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to use the myMethod found in TestActivity, but the application crashes.
If I put the same method inside MainActivity and then use

```
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).myMethod();
```

The code works, but it won't let me call a method found in the TestActivity?
Thanks

my Main Activity
    package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {

     ...    
    }
```

GamesFragment

```
 public class GamesFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        Button showButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Btn_Show);
        showButton.setOnClickListener (this);

        return rootView;
}

    public interface YourInterface {
        public void yourMethod();
        }

        private YourInterface yourInterface ;

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Activity activity){
                super.onAttach(activity);
                try {
                    yourInterface = (TestActivity) activity;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement YourInterface");
                  }

            }


        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Btn_Show:
                yourInterface .yourMethod();
                break;
            }
            }

}
```

Test Activity

```
   public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, YourInterface {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_test);

    }

    public void yourMethod(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Log Cat

```
11-02 19:33:15.468: E/Trace(1952): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-02 19:33:15.560: D/AndroidRuntime(1952): Shutting down VM
11-02 19:33:15.560: W/dalvikvm(1952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62fa288)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity@a6d853c0 must implement YourInterface
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment.onAttach(GamesFragment.java:40)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:883)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which activity hosts the fragment? is it MainActivity

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes MainActivity shows the fragments using tabs

Comment: then how do you access a method in TestActivity? makes sense?

Comment: @Raghunandan I understand. But is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: why is that you need it. do you navigate from fragment to testactivity?

Comment: @Raghunandan I can navigate from fragment to testactivity using intent which works. But I have methods in TestActivity that I want to be able to use from inside my fragment screens.

Comment: then use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` and get the value required.

Comment: @Raghunandan Would I be able to use those without showing the actual TestActivity screen?

Comment: if your activity is not started how can you access a method inside it not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
11-02 19:33:15.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity@a6d853c0 must implement YourInterface
```

Change

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {

     ...    
    }
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener , YourInterface  {

     ...    
    }
```

Comment: Hi, would this not give me the same error as the method I am trying to call is not in MainActivity but is in TestActivity?

Comment: the context will call the Activity where `Fragment` started from and prevent the errors

Comment: Sorry my bad , do just like what is said and change `public void myMethod()` to `public static void myMethod()`

Comment: Isn't changing methods to static bad practice?

Comment: @AndroidLearner is the test activity in the activity back stack.

Comment: @Raghunandan at the point I am trying to call the method, the activity has not been displayed yet. I will use intents to show the activity and then use the method - thanks for your help.

Comment: change `((Activity) context).myMethod();` to  ` TestActivity.myMethod();` and its shall work but don't forget to change myMethod() to static

Comment: I use get sharedpreferences in one of the method, and so I cannot change the method to static.

Comment: Okay then to call `myMethod()` from `TestActivity` use `((TestActivity) context).myMethod();` its shall work fine where is the problem ??

Comment: This causes the application to crash. As MainActivity is the activity hosting the fragments in tabs
TestActivity is just another activity I have that contains a method I want to run from inside the fragments.

Comment: the application crashed because `TestActivity` is null , define `TestActivity` in `MainActivity` then call it from `Fragment` I'll change my answer keep updated

Comment: Hi, how do I define test Activity in MainActivity?

Comment: before `onCreate` define it like this `TestActivity testactivity` and after `onCreate` add ` testactivity = new TestActivity()` , but you have to implement `YourInterface ` in Main class check the answer above

Answer (score 0):

You should use interface:
activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, YourInterface {
...

@Override
public void yourMethod(){
//smth to do
}
}
```

fragment:

```
...
public interface YourInterface {
public void yourMethod();
}

private YourInterface yourInterface ;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            yourInterface = (YourInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
              throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement YourInterface");
          }

    }

...
      public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Btn_TUD_Show:
                yourInterface .yourMethod();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying cannot make static reference to method

Comment: Are you sure? It is absolutely simple way. Double check your code.

Comment: Note: yourInterface = (YourInterface) activity;
Then you use object yourInterface (NOT YourInterface).

Comment: not letting me paste the code into a comment as too many characters, how can i show my code on this post please?

Comment: As you can see in logcat, you got lost in activities. You start main activity but interface implemented in test activity. Edit main activity (add impl. of interface)

Comment: Hi -sorry I am really confused on how to use interface.
MainActivity - shows fragments in tabs.
Test Activity - is an activity that has a method I want to use from inside the fragments.

Comment: my fault. this case you need static ref.

Comment: Thats okay thank you for trying.
So would I have to make the method static.
I cannot change a method that uses get shared preferences to static.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer with two activities.

Test activity:

```
...
private TestActivity instance;
public static TestActivity getTestActivity (){
if (instance == null) instance = new TextActivity ();
return instance;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
...
instance = this;
...}
...
```

and fragment :

```
TestActivity .getTestActivity ().yourMethod();
```

Comment: Hi Alek - really appreciate you trying, this is still causing the application to crash when calling the method.

Comment: ok, actually your task is pretty weird but I got excitement.
Another one way to solve it is to use LocalBradcasts. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742010/interaction-between-activity-and-sticky-service/19742096#19742096 If you need more detail how to use it in your case inform me.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for trying to help.
I havn't used broadcast before so could you please explain how it works and I will try to implement it. Thanks

Comment: I have tried using the code but I am not sure how to use the broadcast

Comment: 1. register broadcast receiver in your test activity;
2. when you need send local broadcast from where ever you need
3. receiver will "catch" broadst and execute onReceive method.|
That is how it is work.

Comment: Hi,
tried this. Created a new class called LocalMessage with the LocalMessage extend Intent code. 

Then put registerBroadcast in my TestActivity

Getting an error on         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YourService.LocalMessage.BROADCAST);
YourService is underlined in red.

Comment: Not sure where to put sendLocalMessage() method
and how would i send local broadcast from my fragment

Comment: Try to get insight of code. I gave you way, implementation up to you... You should send broadcast or from some Activity or from Service  or even from AsynkTask. Then you catch it by receiver. The question is what if your TestActivity was not started. In this case nothing will happen.

Comment: if you created new java file you must use this  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(LocalMessage.BROADCAST); instead of  ...YourService.LocalMessage.BROADCAST...

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I cannot get it to work.
Thanks for helping- appreciate your support.
I'll just try and have the methods in the fragment so I don't need to use TestActivity to call them.
Kind regards.